# RTK Query useGetQuery { data } turns into { _data }, why?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Not sure what I have done. All the following destructuring:

```
const {data, isSuccess} = useGetQuery();
```

has become:

```
const {_data, isSuccess} = useGetQuery();
```

and says `data` doesn't exist, only `_data` exists. I don't remember changing any configuration. Could anyone tell what is causing this?

[image]

Error is:

`Property 'data' does not exist on type. const data: any`

---

As a reference here is my Api slice, it is very standard:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { GetResponse, GetRequest, mapResponse } from '../dto';

export const getApiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'getApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'localhost:3000/api',
    prepareHeaders: headers => {
      headers.set('X-Api-Key', '********');
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  keepUnusedDataFor: 999,
  endpoints: builder => ({
    //get query
    get: builder.query<GetResponse | undefined, GetRequest>({
      query: ({ keywords, page = 1, perPage = 20 }) =>
        `get/?keywords=${keywords}&page=${page}&perPage=${perPage}`,
      transformResponse: raw => {
        try {
          return mapResponse(raw);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('get error:', error);
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
}); 
export const { useGetQuery, usePrefetch } = getApiSlice;
```